# Is it possible to "shape" area impacted by radiation shielding during interstellar travels?

Tags: interstellar-travel, radiation, shielding, design-alternative

If I have uderstood radiation/other shielding described in other questions correctly...it will be among other things provided by magnetic field(s) generated by superconductors.

Is it possible to shape this magnetic field?

And if so is it possible to use it not so much to deflect particals that come to the ship from the front but rather to change their direction just a little bit but sooner.
Kind of like with aerodinamics - but insted of air molecules it will be gama radiation and other particals and the "shape of the object" would be the shape of the generated magnetic field.
I was thinking about the shape that would have a long spike in the direction the ship is heading.Could it improve efficiency and block more easily the particals from that dirrection?

Comment: Only charged particles can be deflected by magnetic fields. Gamma radiation, in particular is not charged. At high velocities (eg for interstellar travel) neutral hydrogen atoms are also a problem, although they could possibly be ionised by lasers or electron beams aimed ahead of the spacecraft.

Comment: So there will be something like constant laser or electron beam in the front of the ship? Or it will be used only when needed...if that is the case how is neutral hydrogen detected brfore impact?

Comment: I have one one more following question. Can we create really strong steady ray of particals in limited area. What I mean is like a frame 4meters to 4meters in which high energy particals are emited from one side to another. Something like gamaray laser emineted on 4 meters lenght and captured after it travel 4 meters on the other side of the frame. Than we put this "frame" as a front window in front of the ship. Would that help block any particals comming from that dirrection?

Comment: The shape of the magnetic field will only affect the orientation of objects. Relocation of objects is done by a magnetic gradient. I suggest reading up more on magnetic gradients and asking a new question.

Comment: Nasa is actually researching this.  https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2005/24jun_electrostatics